# How can I accept end user license agreement for ttf-mscorefonts-installer?

Tags: software-installation

I was trying to install a software. This pop up appeared

[image]

And now I can not do anything, I tried to press okay but it doesn't work. What is the solution of this? Which button exactly I need to press? I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.1.

Answer (score 2):

Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> key, when `<OK>` is highlighted press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Answer (score 0):

oh thats tricky once it happened to me also while installing virtual box just press the down arrow until it goes to ok and highlights it and hit enter after it highlights

good luck pal